# Postgres: Trying to streamline a DB minimization script

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On ec2-user@'s crontab $(crontab -e), their are several scripts running that create a backup of our database.

ec2-user@ ->   ~  $ crontab -l
30 7 * * * /home/ec2-user/db/dump.sh
30 5 * * * cd /home/ec2-user/code/dev/utils/db_dump/ && node index.js >> /home/ec2-user/output.txt
15 9 * * * /home/ec2-user/code/dev/utils/db_dump/dump.sh >> /home/ec2-user/output_dump.txt
15 12 * * * /home/ec2-user/code/dev/remote_development/staging/cron/staging_cron.sh
0 17 * * * /home/ec2-user/code/dev/utils/looker-contrave-users/contrave_users.sh

/home/ec2-user/db/dump.sh is our standard Daily database backup. It creates a single daily dump stored at /home/ec2-user/db/master.dump. We use that dump for several things. 1 A backup, and 2 A source for development database creations. This script works as it needs to.

cd /home/ec2-user/code/dev/utils/db_dump/ && node index.js >> /home/ec2-user/output.txt
^ This is what actually creates the minimal backup dump of our database. It basically restores the full backup to a database called pg-webhooks-dump, then runs an SQL file that deletes entries that are created more than 30 days ago. Then runs another pg_dump on that DB to get the minimal dump.
There is also /home/ec2-user/code/dev/utils/db_dump/dump.sh, which I believe is what actually processes the dump. You should look into that though, because I only took a quick look.

Ultimately, We want to simplify the entire minimization process for the DB so that it does the following:
1. It doesn't require a middle man database to dump into, then dump out of. Ultimately, it should just do a SELECT on anything newer than 30 days(Atleast thats my idea, you can probably think up a better way to do it).
2. A minimal database is only used by developers, so I would like to give developers the choice of how far back or what date ranges they want for their backup. 30 days gives us about a 30gb backup. I would like to give devs the ability to pull, 2 days, 5 days, 10 days, 15 days, and 30 days. A simple bash script is all they need.

What I have is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "get run delete.sql"
psql --username xxxxx --port xxxxx --host xxxxxx-f "/home/ec2-user/code/dev/utils/db_dump/delete.sql"
echo "done deleting, now dump"
pg_dump --username xxxx --dbname xxxx --port 5432 --host yyyyy -N zzzz -F c -b -v -f "/home/ec2-user/db/master_reduced.dump"
echo "done dumping now delete DB instance"
aws rds delete-db-instance --db-instance-identifier prod-webhooks-dump --skip-final-snapshot

echo "Now lets create a new DB from staging-webhooks-dump"
cd /home/ec2-user/code/dev/utils/db_dump/ && node small_db.js
echo "done creating, now lets restore from dump"
pg_restore -v -h staging-db -U master -d master /home/ec2-user/db/master_reduced.dump
echo "lets delete the old snapshot"
aws rds delete-db-snapshot --db-snapshot-identifier "staging--dump"
echo "now lets kill it and snapshot it"
aws rds delete-db-instance --db-instance-identifier staging--test --final-db-snapshot-identifier "staging--dump"
```

Now I know in MSSQL there is a SELECT TO function, but I am not sure how to do this in Postgres (which I am super new in) or if there is an easy way to maybe variablize this to allow for the dev to say "I want 1 day's data" on the new DB (which on a different VPC)

Comment: [pg_sample](https://github.com/mla/pg_sample) might be the solution you're looking for, as it allows you to retrieve N rows for specific tables.

Comment: Do you really think a script like this is going to work the first time?